# Android linear layout, how to match remaining parent?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-linearlayout

I am going to create a listview with two button at the bottom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="400dp"
                android:id="@android:id/list"></ListView>
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Add Task"
                android:id="@+id/addTaskButton"></Button>
        <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Add Task2"
                android:id="@+id/addTaskButton2"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

How to make the listview match the height to the remaining parent?

If I set a height to listview

```
            android:layout_height="400dp"
```

this is not suitable to all device

If I set match_parent

```
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

The listview will over the buttons at the bottom

Comment: Make use of `android:layout_weight` parameter, then you can adjust it accordingly no matter what screen size is.

Comment: Make use of RelativeLayout then. Align linear layout containing buttons below the listview and align it in bottom of parent. You have params in relative layout to acheive that.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in the above code.. try and run it using hieght as wrap

Comment: Use RealativeLayout as parent and give button layout property "android:layout_alignParentBottom=true" and listview layout property "android:layout_above="id of button layout"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you set its height to `0dp` and it's layout weight to `1`, it will fill out the remaining space. Also, you don't need the `LinearLayout` surrounding the `ListView`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@android:id/list" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Add Task"
            android:id="@+id/addTaskButton" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Add Task2"
            android:id="@+id/addTaskButton2" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: "set its height to 0dp and it's layout weight to 1" is the key, thanks, it worked!!!

Answer (score 1):

This will work and I have also reduced number of lines in your code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addTaskButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Add Task" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addTaskButton2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Add Task2" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.9" >

        <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@android:id/list"></ListView>
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp" 
            android:layout_weight="0.1">

        <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Add Task"
                android:id="@+id/addTaskButton"></Button>
        <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Add Task2"
                android:id="@+id/addTaskButton2"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this layout :

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/lv_button"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_bottom"
         >
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lv_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_bottom"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_left"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_right"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="0.0dip"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_right"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"           
            android:text="Button1"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"            
            android:layout_width="0.0dip"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_left"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"            
            android:text="Button2"
             />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use weight sum. Refer this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) to know about weightsum

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" android:weightSum="10">

   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="8"
       >

    <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:id="@android:id/list"></ListView>
 </LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0" 
                    android:layout_weight="2"
      >

    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Add Task"
            android:id="@+id/addTaskButton"></Button>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Add Task2"
            android:id="@+id/addTaskButton2"></Button>
   </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:id="@android:id/list"></ListView>
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Add Task"
            android:id="@+id/addTaskButton"></Button>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Add Task2"
            android:id="@+id/addTaskButton2"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```